# To bind value in TextBox field of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have one form in which GridView contains 1 "rate" field in TextBox. The rate field is not added to database.
Now on another form (report generation), in GridView i want to show the value of the rate field which is in first form,
How can i do this? Waiting for reply..

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as a session variable if you don't want to save it anywhere.

```
Session["rate"] = rate;
```

and to read it:

```
rate = Session["rate"];
```